# How do I get a header to the front?

Tags: menu, position

On my site knipknip.helenparkhurst.net/kapper is a login header but if i scroll down the menu go's over it. But I want the header to be on top of everything so that the header is always 100% visible. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a z-index:

```
#header {
    background-color: #282828;
    border-width: 0;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

But be careful, the element you placed the z-index on always needs a position, else it wont work

Comment: Thank you very much it works. I wanted to know this for a really long time.

Comment: Not a problem, 999 is ofcourse a very high number, if you are going to use z-index in more than 1 place you might want to use more realistic numbers